# Radeon GPU locks up under 18.04; "ring 0 stalled" spam appears in TTY1

Tags: drivers, 18.04, hardware, radeon, amd-graphics

My `radeon` driver can't run `glxgears` 100% of the time (most of the time it does work, but sometimes it hangs), and hangs instantly or after a few seconds when trying to run anything else.

When it hangs, either the game window or the entire desktop freezes up. Switching to TTY1 with Ctrl+Alt+F1 shows lots of error messages like these constantly being printed (usually it's just for ring 0, sometimes it's for ring 0 and 3, once or twice it was for 0, 3 and 4):

```
[  129.372362] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 11228msec
[  129.820391] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: ring 3 stalled for more than 11676msec
```

Sometimes, it isn't even possible to switch to TTY1, and I have to force-reboot the system with Alt+SysRq+REISUB.

Software:

- Kernel 4.15.0-39-generic
- Xubuntu 18.04.1 (installed with UEFI boot, Secure Boot disabled, and disk encryption)
- Dualboot with Windows 10, in which the GPU has always worked fine
- Switchable graphics is enabled in BIOS

Hardware:

- Lenovo E50-80 laptop
- Intel i5-5200U CPU with Intel 5500 graphics
- AMD R5 M330 GPU (I think this is the same chip as the 8670A, 8670M, 8690M, and R5 M430, and the codename is HAINAN. I've noticed a lot of other Linux users on the Internet having trouble with this particular card, but it should be supported by `radeon`.)

Output of `glxinfo` and `lshw -c video`: see https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RvnN4Prcjm/

Output of `sudo avivotool regs all`:

```
error: cannot map ctrl region: Operation not permitted
fatal error: unable to see card
```

Partial output of `dmesg` after `glxgears` freezes:

```
[ 2785.769588] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: WB enabled
[ 2785.769590] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c00 and cpu addr 0x00000000001bfff9
[ 2785.769592] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c04 and cpu addr 0x00000000a1d8536e
[ 2785.769593] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c08 and cpu addr 0x000000008ef3a8c5
[ 2785.769594] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c0c and cpu addr 0x000000003f7ad0b8
[ 2785.769596] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c10 and cpu addr 0x00000000b08ba6e8
[ 2786.006091] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
[ 2786.006097] [drm] ring test on 1 succeeded in 1 usecs
[ 2786.006102] [drm] ring test on 2 succeeded in 1 usecs
[ 2786.006111] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 4 usecs
[ 2786.006118] [drm] ring test on 4 succeeded in 4 usecs
[ 2786.006232] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[ 2786.006348] [drm] ib test on ring 1 succeeded in 0 usecs
[ 2786.006462] [drm] ib test on ring 2 succeeded in 0 usecs
[ 2786.006478] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[ 2786.006491] [drm] ib test on ring 4 succeeded in 0 usecs
[ 2805.115865] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: ring 3 stalled for more than 10108msec
[ 2805.115877] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000880 last fence id 0x0000000000000885 on ring 3)
[ 2805.211969] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 10204msec
[ 2805.211982] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x00000000000003f1 last fence id 0x00000000000003f5 on ring 0)
[ 2805.243854] asynchronous wait on fence radeon:radeon.gfx:3f5 timed out
[ 2805.243861] asynchronous wait on fence radeon:radeon.gfx:3f3 timed out
[ 2805.566061] show_signal_msg: 13 callbacks suppressed
[ 2805.566064] panel-9-pulseau[2085]: segfault at 90 ip 00007f31cb797618 sp 00007ffd9fd4ae30 error 4 in libgdk-3.so.0.2200.30[7f31cb739000+eb000]
[ 2805.576047] panel-7-statusn[2082]: segfault at 90 ip 00007f47028e1618 sp 00007ffe56773fc0 error 4 in libgdk-3.so.0.2200.30[7f4702883000+eb000]
[ 2805.576647] panel-6-indicat[2080]: segfault at 90 ip 00007f19989cb618 sp 00007ffdf6b9a5a0 error 4 in libgdk-3.so.0.2200.30[7f199896d000+eb000]
[ 2805.578174] panel-5-notific[2079]: segfault at 90 ip 00007f5c37e7d618 sp 00007ffc41930d90 error 4 in libgdk-3.so.0.2200.30[7f5c37e1f000+eb000]
[ 2805.581612] panel-8-power-m[2083]: segfault at 90 ip 00007f5f9c8ce618 sp 00007ffd08911f50 error 4 in libgdk-3.so.0.2200.30[7f5f9c870000+eb000]
[ 2805.628005] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: ring 3 stalled for more than 10620msec
[ 2805.628110] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000000000880 last fence id 0x0000000000000885 on ring 3)
[ 2805.641291] terminator[7124]: segfault at 90 ip 00007f8d2a637275 sp 00007fff197601e0 error 4 in libgdk-3.so.0.2200.30[7f8d2a5d9000+eb000]
[ 2805.723849] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 10716msec
[ 2805.723899] radeon 0000:0a:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x00000000000003f1 last fence id 0x00000000000003f5 on ring 0)
```

Output of `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` (yes, this is with sudo):

```
 cat: /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch: Operation not permitted
```

Until recently, it would output that the AMD card was `DynOff` when it wasn't being used and `DynPwr` if it was, and only the `IGD` (Intel) GPU ever had a `+` next to it. `echo DIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` had no effect. I don't know what I've changed, but it no longer lets me read the file.

Things I've tried:

- `radeontool` - `error: cannot find Radeon device`
- Adding nomodeset to the boot options - neither the Intel nor the AMD GPU is detected by the system, and everything is rendered with llvmpipe (resulting in poor framerates)
- `xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink 1 0` - no discernible effect
- `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati` - the package is already installed
- Running `sudo bash -c 'echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch'` before and after each invocation of `DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears` - no discernible effect, freezes still occur sometimes
- ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers - the updated Mesa packages install but don't fix anything
- ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa - the updated Mesa packages install but don't fix anything
- Installing `amdgpu` from the AMD website - the driver installs but the X server doesn't start after I reboot; AMD's website has a warning about X servers not starting if they aren't running on the AMD card (so it's trying to run on the Intel integrated GPU). Uninstalling the driver from TTY1 makes X work again.
- `./amdgpu-install --px` - the installation fails with `E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-video-modesetting-amdgpu-pro`
- Disabling switchable graphics in BIOS - the AMD card cannot be detected by `xrandr` or `lshw`
- Xubuntu 18.10 - doesn't fix the issue - I was originally trying to fix this on 18.10 but downgraded to 18.04 after the `amdgpu` installer broke apt completely because AMD only supports LTS releases
- Clean install - doesn't fix the issue
- Toggling Secure Boot - no effect
- Probably some other things that I've forgotten

Software tested, with `DRI_PRIME=1` prefixed to the command (all this works fine on the Intel GPU):

- `minetest` - loads the menu fine but inevitably hangs a few seconds after loading a world - the controls do work for those few seconds
- Google Earth - freezes after a few seconds, but the controls do work for the first few seconds
- `glxgears` - runs most of the time, hangs rarely
- `openttd`, `firefox`, `gimp` - runs fine, apparently
- `steam` - gets as far as the Steam Library window, which immediately freezes; eventually random coloured pixels appear along the bottom of the window

Is there anything else I can try to make Radeon work?

Comment: Uh oh, there's a recent bug for the radeon driver that sounds very similar to this: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=107545. I can't say for sure whether it's the same problem, of course.

Comment: Shouldn't have upgraded from 16.04 - any idea if this has been fixed, short of manually patching things?

Answer (score 2):

A few days ago I had the same problem with random desktop freezes, artifacts, shutdowns on my 9 year old Sony Vaio which has an AMD GPU (I'm using Ubuntu 20.10 and sometimes Windows 10). I saw some temporary artifacts (vertical lines, dots, bad 3D graphics) a few years ago, but in recent days they are starting to appear constantly for no reason to me.

[image: vertical artifacts]

These artifacts, random blocks are not dependent on the OS (Windows or Linux), drivers etc (however I noticed that on linux it is easier to bring up the symptoms). I also connected the second monitor via the HDMI cable and experienced the same symptoms. It is really easy to confuse these symptoms with driver's fault. In my case the problem is not at the software level but at the hardware level. In short, after some time (10-15 mins) of using the computer it heats up more (which is normal) but the temperature dilates the GPU chip from the motherboard which causes it to physically lose the connection.
I saw the same driver's messages like below, because there is a bad connection with the motherboard:

```
[...]
asynchronous wait on fence radeon:radeon.gfx:3f5 timed out
[...]
ring 0 stalled for more than 10716msec
[...]
```

The only way to try to fix or postpone the problem is to reflow the GPU using a heat gun. If you search for "GPU reflow" you will find everything you need to know. The only thing I should say for whoever will encounter this case is **DO NOT PUT the motherboard or GPU in the oven**, this dumb homemade method is used by lazy folks to melt the solder and at the same time burn everything or make a working chip / motherboard completely dead. You can really help your GPU just by reflowing it. Good luck!

[image: gpu reflowing]

p.s from what I gather, the reballing will not help, since the problem is inside the chip in 99% of cases. Or replace the chip, or the entire laptop. This is like a "disease" but at electronics level.

Comment: The problem came back after 3 years of daily use. That's something I had to wait for since the GPU temperature was at 70-80 degrees for the entire month of July. The GPU is literally desoldered again. I'm sure I can fix it with reflowing, but I've bought another laptop by now.